# Why does my vanilla cream filling soften my copycat Oreo sandwich biscuits?

Tags: cookies, filling

My filling is low sugar and I use oil, not butter or shortening.

Edit: Filling ingredients 
      500 grams cashew nuts
      333 grams milk powder
      175 grams confectioner's sugar
about 120 grams water

I might have added some oil because it was too thick. Water was added was for the same reason.

Edit: Too thick to spread. But never mind. I finally found a commercial recipe.

Comment: Is there any water present in your filling?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post with the recipe or at least a list of ingredients, please?

Comment: "too thick" for what? Too thick to use, or too thick to blend?